# How can I run a ft-plugin with the new built-in package manager in Vim?

Tags: plugin-system, packages

I'm testing the new built-in package manager. From [`:h packages`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#packages):

```
When Vim starts up, after processing your .vimrc, it scans all directories in
'packpath' for plugins under the "pack/*/start" directory.  First all those
directories are added to 'runtimepath'.  Then all the plugins are loaded.
See packload-two-steps for how these two steps can be useful.
```

My folders are looking in this way:

```
.vim
  |--pack
    |--javascript
      |--start
        |--vim-javascript
          |--ftdetect
            |-- javascript.vim
          |--ftplugin
            |--javascript.vim
          |--indent
            |--javascript.vim
```

When I'm opening a .js file, I get this log:

```
sourcing /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/syntax/javascript.vim    
sourcing /Users/me/.vim/pack/javascript/start/vim-javascript/syntax/javascript.vim    
sourcing /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin/javascript.vim    
sourcing /Users/me/.vim/pack/javascript/start/vim-javascript/ftplugin/javascript.vim    
sourcing /opt/local/share/vim/vim74/indent/javascript.vim    
sourcing /Users/me/.vim/pack/javascript/start/vim-javascript/indent/javascript.vim
```

This seems to look fine, but the plugin doesn't work at all. Where is the problem?

**EDIT:**
I'm using Vim version 7.4.1797, huge version without GUI on OSX. The plugin, that I try to load, is [pangloss/vim-javascript](https://github.com/pangloss/vim-javascript). With pathogen, plugin is loading, no problem.

Comment: I'm guessing from the log that this is a minimal setup? Oddly, in my case, the file in `pack/*/start/*/ftplugin` was loaded before the one in `/usr/share/vim/vim74/ftplugin`. Which version of Vim?

Comment: @muru I give an update. I use Vim version 7.4.1797, huge version without GUI on OSX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution. I changed runtimepath to bring `pack/*/start/*/ftplugin` in front of the PATH

```
set runtimepath^=~/Users/me/.vim/pack/
```

Works for all ft plugin. This is a workaround, maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is vim's [filetype detection](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/4475b623960671898dac6a72b13a8d140402afa6/runtime/filetype.vim#L2770) uses:

```
runtime! ftdetect/*.vim
```

The help for `runtime[!] [where] {file} ..` says:

> Read Ex commands from {file} in each directory given by 'runtimepath' and/or 'packpath'.
>
> [snip]
>
> When [where] is omitted only 'runtimepath' is used. Other values:
>
> START  search under "start" in 'packpath'
>      OPT    search under "opt" in 'packpath'
>      PACK   search under "start" and "opt" in 'packpath'
>      ALL    first use 'runtimepath', then search under "start" and "opt" in 'packpath'

When I added `ALL` to the filetype detection line quoted above, it picked up filetype files in the packages.  I.e.:

```
runtime! ALL ftdetect/*.vim
```

Comment: I opened [vim#1679](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/1679) to clarify this.